# How to dynamically set Azure Search's returned document size?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I know that by default Azure search will return 50 rows and maximum, it can return 1000 in one request. Then I need to use the continueToken to get the rest.

However, when I use SearchServiceClient and SearchParameters to do a query with the SDK, seems I can't pass a parameter to say how many rows I want to return in one request. Did I miss something? There is my simple code, just to return everything.

(what I want is that for certain scenario, return max 50 rows per request, but in other scenario, return 1000 rows per request and loop to get the rest).

```
var _searchClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(apiKey));
var _indexClient = _searchClient.Indexes.GetClient("unit");

SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters() { SearchMode = SearchMode.All};
var result=  _indexClient.Documents.Search(null , sp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Cognitive Search provides a model class `SearchParameters` in `Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models` namespace for the .NET SDK. You can set the `Top` and `Skip` properties to control the number of returned docs.

Refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters?view=azure-dotnet) for SearchParameters for more properties. The following article gives examples of using this parameters with search - [How to use Azure Cognitive Search from a .NET Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Cognitive Search, you use the `$count`, `$top`, and `$skip` parameters to return the number of search results . The following example shows a sample request for total hits on an index called "online-catalog", returned as `@odata.count`:

```
GET /indexes/online-catalog/docs?search=*&$top=15&$skip=0&$count=true
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout#total-hits-and-page-counts).